# Firebase console and google dev console blank page issues

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-console

I have an issue with loading page getting a blank page. It's happen in firebase console and Google dev console. I use incognito mode, login, then get the same issue. i use both firefox and chrome. in the firefox console log i get this 404 error message

GET [https://www.gstatic.com/*/pantheon/*/js/k=pantheon.pantheon_module_set.id.jFtQq5XQ3tE.O/m=core,jsmod_projectdetail/am=DAqwhQqAhoAQQmpiFHkEKgBAhAkIAQxBAg/rt=j/d=1/rs=ADqnUbOpczU20KGvxrQKHlph8_IyuMsZaw](https://www.gstatic.com/_/pantheon/_/js/k=pantheon.pantheon_module_set.id.jFtQq5XQ3tE.O/m=core,jsmod_projectdetail/am=DAqwhQqAhoAQQmpiFHkEKgBAhAkIAQxBAg/rt=j/d=1/rs=ADqnUbOpczU20KGvxrQKHlph8_IyuMsZaw) [HTTP/2.0 404 Not Found 6564ms]

Anyone knew the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Sorry about the problems with our Firebase Console. We've recently discovered that this problem is related to having Indonesian set at the language in your Google account settings (https://myaccount.google.com/) under "Account Preferences" > "Language and Input Tools".

As a simple workaround, go to https://console.firebase.google.com/?hl=en to temporarily override the language preference. We'll continue to investigate and roll out a fix as soon as we can.

Comment: thx u very much. it's work now. i do the same think with google developer console too.. http://console.developers.google.com/?hl=en

Comment: In case someone is unable to load console, disable AdBlock Plus plugin (and even Disconnect plugin). It somehow creates problem while loading firebase console.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue on Google Cloud console
https://console.cloud.google.com/

OS-Windows (11)

Kaspersky Total Security was installed.

Seems Kaspersky was causing the issue. Fix- go to

```
settings -> Protection -> Anti Banner -> Websites with allowed banners -> Add
```

In `website` field enter `https://console.cloud.google.com/` (status should be active)