# Firebase console is not loading

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I am trying to load my firebase console but it is not working on my laptop.It works fine on other laptops and my mobile but on my laptop it displays loading screen and then nothing.In console it shows 502 gateway error.

I have removed addblock, open console in incognito,firefox,internet explorer, reinstall chrome,change my network, login from another account but nothing works.
These are the questions I have seen to solve this but none of them actually works for me.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/xOWdvmKd7I0

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/5txW1hHXOQA

[Firebase console and google dev console blank page issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320406/firebase-console-and-google-dev-console-blank-page-issues)

Thanks

Comment: You should contact firebase about this. If i remember correctly errors in the 500s are server errors so there wont be anything you can do about it yourself

Comment: For me, It was Issue with the Internet Provider. For me I have change to mobile Internet and different Browser. It worked!.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I resolved it by disabling a chrome extension named CORS.

Thanks

Comment: the Chrome extension "Disconnect" is also blocking firebase

Answer (score 3):

I resolved too, by disabling tampermonkey extension. This might help someone else...

Answer (score 2):

Try Updating your browser to latest version. I solved this by updating Chrome to latest version available.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the chrome and disabled Grammerly. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I solved by disabling "Pop up blocker for Chrome - Poper Blocker" extension.

Answer (score 0):

I have disable all ext. and then I have to changed the Internet Provider, from Broadband to Mobile Internet. It worked.

Comment: some Email-Browsers Extension Issue mightbe. As my client firebase console was loading quick with same Internet and same browser version. Dev firebase is not loading.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was disabling the Ublock

Answer (score -1):

It happened to me too until I changed my internet provider